# Insert values referring to another table

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I have created the following simple `datamodel`:

[image]

I used the following `insert statements` to insert values:

1) Table **Products**:

```
INSERT INTO test.products
(ProductName, Price)
VALUES 
("Product A","99,99"),
("Product B","49,95"), 
("Product C","5,95");
```

2) Table **Orders**:

```
INSERT INTO test.orders
(Customer)
VALUES 
("Customer A"),
("Customer B"), 
("Customer B");
```

All this works fine so far.

---

However, now I also want to insert values into the table `Products_per_Order`. 
As you can see in the `datamodel` the `Products_per_Order` table contains the column `Price`. In this column I want to insert the price referring to the **ID** in the column `Products_idProducts`. Therefore, I tried to go with the following `insert statement` but could not make it work so far:

```
INSERT INTO test.products_per_order
(Orders_idOrders, Products_idProducts, Price, Quantity)
VALUES
("1","1",(Select Price from test.products),"5"),
("1","2",(Select Price from test.products),"4"),
("2","1",(Select Price from test.products),"10"),
("3","2",(Select Price from test.products),"3"),
("3","3",(Select Price from test.products),"9");
```

Do you have any idea how to solve this issue?

Comment: Your query makes no sense.  _Which_ price should be inserted for each row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using `insert . . . select` instead:

```
insert into test.products_per_order (Orders_idOrders, Products_idProducts, Price, Quantity)
    select x.idOrder, x.idProduct, p.price, x.qty
    from (select 1 as idOrder, 2 as idProduct, 5 as qty union all
          select 1 as idOrder, 2 as idProduct, 4 as qty union all
          . . .  -- I've left these out so you can see the structure of the query
          select 3 as idOrder, 3 as idProduct, 9 as qty
         ) x left join
         test.products p
         on p.idProducts = x.idProduct;
```

This makes it much less likely that a typo will result in the wrong price.

Comment: Hi Gordon, thanks for your answer. Workbench is displaying me on line ") x left join" that something is wrong with the query (I also get Error Code: 1064 when I run the statement). I tried to place , or ; after the select statements but could not make it work.

Comment: @Michi . . . This syntax is definitely supported by MySQL.  Perhaps you left an extra `union all` on the last row.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now it is working. I only had to change the line "on p.idProduct = x.idProduct;" because an s was missing "on p.idProducts = x.idProduct;".

Comment: Hi Gordon, do you have an idea for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54350789/getting-conditions-for-where-clause-from-a-table-of-criterias

Answer (score 1):

You can use sub-query to extract it from the Products table.

```
("2","1","Select Price from test.products where test.products.idProducts = '1')","10");
```

Answer (score 1):

You are close, but you when you have `(Select Price from test.products)` this selects all prices from the test.products table. You need to make it so it returns one value.

```
INSERT INTO test.products_per_order
(Orders_idOrders, Products_idProducts, Price, Quantity)
VALUES
("1","1",(Select Price from test.products WHERE test.products.idProducts = '1'),"5"),
("1","2",(Select Price from test.products WHERE test.products.idProducts = '2'),"4"),
("2","1",(Select Price from test.products WHERE test.products.idProducts = '1'),"10"),
("3","2",(Select Price from test.products WHERE test.products.idProducts = '2'),"3"),
("3","3",(Select Price from test.products WHERE test.products.idProducts = '3'),"9");
```