# Insert statement with calculated column

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I have created the following simple `DataModel`:

[image]

I used the following `insert statements` to insert values:

1) Table **Products**:

```
INSERT INTO test.products
(ProductName, Price)
VALUES 
("Product A","99,99"),
("Product B","49,95"), 
("Product C","5,95");
```

2) Table **Orders**:

```
INSERT INTO test.orders
(Customer)
VALUES 
("Customer A"),
("Customer B"), 
("Customer B");
```

All this works fine so far.

---

Now, in the table `Products_per_Order` I want to calculate the last column `OrderValue` by multiplying the `Price` with the `Quantity`.
Therefore, I tried to go with the following two options referring to the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54311635/insert-values-referring-to-another-table) but could not make them work yet:

**Note:** The column `Price` is getting the prices based on the `idProduct` from the table `Products`. 
 
This functionality already works. Only the multiplication with the quantity does not work.

**Option 1:**

```
INSERT INTO test.products_per_order
(Orders_idOrders, Products_idProducts, Price, Quantity, OrderValue)
VALUES
("1","1",(Select Price from test.products where test.products.idProducts = "1"),"5",(Price * Quantity)),
("1","2",(Select Price from test.products where test.products.idProducts = "2"),"4",(Price * Quantity)),
("2","1",(Select Price from test.products where test.products.idProducts = "1"),"10",(Price * Quantity)),
("3","2",(Select Price from test.products where test.products.idProducts = "2"),"3",(Price * Quantity)),
("3","3",(Select Price from test.products where test.products.idProducts = "3"),"9",(Price * Quantity));
```

**Option 2:**

```
INSERT INTO test.products_per_order 
(Orders_idOrders, Products_idProducts, Price, Quantity, OrderValue)
    SELECT m.idOrder, m.idProduct, p.price, m.qty, p.price * m.qty
    FROM (SELECT 1 as idOrder, 1 as idProduct, 5 as qty UNION ALL
          SELECT 1 as idOrder, 2 as idProduct, 4 as qty UNION ALL
          SELECT 2 as idOrder, 1 as idProduct, 10 as qty UNION ALL
          SELECT 3 as idOrder, 2 as idProduct, 3 as qty UNION ALL
          SELECT 3 as idOrder, 3 as idProduct, 9 as qty
         ) m
    LEFT JOIN test.products p on p.idProducts = m.idProduct;
```

Do you have any idea how to solve this issue?

Comment: What errors are you getting from Option 2?

Comment: Error Code: 1292. Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '99,99'

Comment: Sounds like you might have `Price` stored using `,` as the decimal separator instead of `.`?

Comment: Thanks man. That was exactly the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With reference to the comments below the question the issue is that the `prices` in the table `Products` need to be stored using `.` as the decimal separator instead of `,`

If you modify the `INSERT STATEMENT` of the table `Products` to:

```
INSERT INTO test.products
(ProductName, Price)
VALUES 
("Product A","99.99"),
("Product B","49.95"), 
("Product C","5.95");
```

and then run the code in **Option 2** everything works.

```
INSERT INTO test.products_per_order 
(Orders_idOrders, Products_idProducts, Price, Quantity, OrderValue)
    SELECT m.idOrder, m.idProduct, p.price, m.qty, p.price * m.qty
    FROM (SELECT 1 as idOrder, 1 as idProduct, 5 as qty UNION ALL
          SELECT 1 as idOrder, 2 as idProduct, 4 as qty UNION ALL
          SELECT 2 as idOrder, 1 as idProduct, 10 as qty UNION ALL
          SELECT 3 as idOrder, 2 as idProduct, 3 as qty UNION ALL
          SELECT 3 as idOrder, 3 as idProduct, 9 as qty
         ) m
    LEFT JOIN test.products p on p.idProducts = m.idProduct;
```

Answer (score 1):

You wrote that `OrderValue` is a calculated column, why not let the database calculate it for you?

Use [alter table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-table-generated-columns.html) to change the `OrderValue` column to a generated column like this:

```
alter table test.products_per_order 
modify column OrderValue int generated always as (Price * Quantity) stored;
```

This way, you don't need to insert it at all - and your insert becomes like this:

```
INSERT INTO test.products_per_order 
(Orders_idOrders, Products_idProducts, Price, Quantity)
    SELECT m.idOrder, m.idProduct, p.price, m.qty
    FROM (SELECT 1 as idOrder, 1 as idProduct, 5 as qty UNION ALL
          SELECT 1 as idOrder, 2 as idProduct, 4 as qty UNION ALL
          SELECT 2 as idOrder, 1 as idProduct, 10 as qty UNION ALL
          SELECT 3 as idOrder, 2 as idProduct, 3 as qty UNION ALL
          SELECT 3 as idOrder, 3 as idProduct, 9 as qty
         ) m
    LEFT JOIN test.products p on p.idProducts = m.idProduct;
```

Comment: Hi Zohar, thanks a lot for your answer. I run the INSERT INTO statement first which went through perfectly. Afterwards, I started the ALTER TABLE statement but got the Error Code: 1292. Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '99,99'.

Comment: Just figured out that the issue results from using , as the decimal separator instead of . in the table Products. Once this is changed everything works.

Comment: Sorry, it was a copy-paste mistake leaving the data type of the generated column as `int`. Clearly it should be `double`.