# Getting conditions for WHERE clause from a table of criterias

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I created the following simple `DataModel`:

[image]

And I filled the tables with the following Data:

1) Table **Customer**

```
INSERT INTO test.customer
(CustomerName, Country, RegistrationDate)
VALUES 
("Customer A","DE","2015-05-03"),
("Customer B","US","2015-07-25"), 
("Customer C","US","2016-02-15"), 
("Customer D","DE","2017-09-21"), 
("Customer E","AU","2018-12-07");
```

2) Table **Orders**

```
INSERT INTO test.orders
(idCustomer, PaymentMethod, OrderDate, OrderValue)
VALUES 
("1","CreditCard","2015-05-04","500"),
("1","PayPal","2015-11-18","200"), 
("3","PayPal","2017-09-04","300"), 
("2","Invoice","2018-04-30","100");
```

3) Table **Criterias**

```
INSERT INTO test.criterias
(Country, MinimumOrderValue)
VALUES 
("DE","300"),
("US","150"), 
("AU","200");
```

Afterwards, I created a query to get `Customers` and their `Orders` based on the criterias `Country` and `OrderValue`:

```
SELECT 
test.customer.idCustomer, CustomerName, Country,
test.orders.OrderValue

FROM test.customer
LEFT JOIN test.customer_info ON test.customer.idCustomer = test.customer_info.idCustomer
LEFT JOIN test.orders ON test.customer.idCustomer = test.orders.idCustomer

WHERE 
Country = "US" AND OrderValue >= "150"
OR Country = "DE" AND OrderValue >= "300" 
OR country = "AU" AND OrderValue >= "200";
```

All this works fine so far.

---

However, instead of having the criterias in the `WHERE` clause within the SQL query they should be stored in a seperate table called `Criterias`. The query should then get the datas from this table and apply them exactly like it does now in the query above.

What do I have to change in my code to achieve this?

Comment: It's good programming practice to qualify all columns when several tables are involved. E.g. `test.orders.Country`... ?

Comment: Tip 2: table aliases!

Comment: How come some columns get properly qualified, and others don't - seems a bit random.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would just `join` the tables or use a subquery in the `where` clause.

The latter is easier to type, so:

```
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM Criterias cr
              WHERE cr.Country = c.Country AND
                    cr.MinOrderValue <=  o.OrderValue
             )
```

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily an answer; too long for a comment...

A valid set of query conditions might look like this...

```
 WHERE (country = "US" AND OrderValue >= 150)
    OR (country = "DE" AND OrderValue >= 300)
    OR (country = "AU" AND OrderValue >= 200);
```

...or indeed (though potentially slower)...

```
WHERE (country,ordervalue) IN(('US',150),('DE',300),('AU',200));
```

Answer (score 1):

As per the above database schema, You have to make one field customer table which is primary and it will map with the table name order. After this you need to use  Join and exists clause in your query.

```
select c.cutomerId, c.customerName, c.country, o.orderValue from customer c, order o where  c.customerId = o.customerId and 
        exists (select * from criteria cr where cr.country = c.country and o.order >= cr.MinimumOrderValue)
```